# Straighten non planar vertices into a circle

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

[image]

[image]

As you can see the vertices are non planar as they are unevenly distributed in the z axis. Is there anyway to make it into a circle like the edgeloop at the bottom of the mesh?

Blendfile:- [image]

Comment: Scale zero in Z axis? Or perhaps it is better to just remodel the whole thing with [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com) Seems easy to accomplish in this case

Comment: Wouldn't that distort the faces above ?

Comment: Probably, but would it be visibly noticeable? Hence the second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for straightening that circle you can do like @[Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) said *(selecting that circle and pressing <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)*

But that topology will sooner or later cause issues, so I did a quick gif to show you an example of fixing that topology, it stretched a few lines but nothing too noticeable on the mesh.

[image]

### What I did:

1. I straightened that circle with
   <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)
2. Since this object can be perfectly mirrored on all sides I deleted
   the left and back part to modify it faster.
3. Then I started to merge some vertices using <kbd>W</kbd>>`Merge`>`At Last`
4. I duplicated that part and inverted with <kbd>S</kbd>*(lock on an Axis)*>`-1`
5. And then I joined all parts using the [Snapping Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) to [Merge at the Closest Vertex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36812/how-do-i-snap-one-vertex-to-the-position-of-another-vertex-in-a-different-object).
6. Finaly I Removed Doubles with <kbd>W</kbd>>`Remove Doubles`
   [image]

   [image]