# How to join two objects.

Tags: faces, mirror

I have two objects that I want to join together on one plane and am having dificulty figuring out how to do this.

I started by mirroring an object I had designed and I want to put the two mirrored halves together, without changing the shape of either.

I am aware of mergeing, but that changes the shape of the objects, which I don't want. I have also tried using various "snaps" none of which have resulted in the desired outcome.

Is there a way to move one object so that the center of a selected face is moved into contact with the center of another selected face, while preserving the shape of the object that is being moved.

Comment: Did you mirror manually and now have two objects - left side and right side? Why not using Mirror modifier for mirroring?

Comment: I used the mirror modifier, I might have set it up wrong but this is something I would like to know how to do regardless, if it is possible.

Comment: If all you want to do is just to move mirrored sides to each other then redo that with Mirror modifier added to one of them, it'll be much easier. If moving mirrored sides manually there should be used snapping 3D cursor to desired face in Edit mode and moving object to cursor in Object mode. See some examples with snapping as well https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39784/snapping-two-objects-by-edge-in-object-mode and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36812/how-do-i-snap-one-vertex-to-the-position-of-another-vertex-in-a-different-object